# Spring Data Jpa, select based on two column values

Tags: sql, jpa, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

Good Morning,

I have the following table:

```
_____________________
Name    Status    Num
A       Good      6
B       Bad       6
C       Bad       7
```

I want to select all rows where "Status = 'Good' AND Num = '6'" OR "Status = 'Bad' AND Num = '7'"

So I would select rows with Names A and C from the above reference data.

I am hoping to be able to pass in two equal sized lists (ordered in the way I desire the query to be constructed), but have been unable to figure this out. The standard queries (SelectXByStatusAndNum) query generates SQL using 'IN' statements, and returns all 3 rows in the above data instead of just two.

Any insight appreciated

Answer (score 0):

I believe the best way is to use a `@Query` annotation in the repository:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "table_name")
public class TableName {

  @Id
  @Basic(optional = false)
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
  @Column(name = "ID")
  private Long id;

  @Column(name = "name")
  private String name;
  @Column(name = "status")
  private String status;
  @Column(name = "num")
  private Integer num;

/**
* getters/setters, etc
**/

public interface TableNameRepository extends CrudRepository<TableName, Long> {

  @Query("select t from TableName t where (status = :status1 and num = :num1 or status = :status2 and num = :num2)")
  List<TableName> findByStatusAndNumOrStatusAndNum(@Param("status1") String status1,
      @Param("num1") Integer num1, @Param("status2") String status2, @Param("num2") Integer num2);
}
```

It's a way to get values for a given parameters. In case of collections as parameters there is no in-box case due to RDBMS concept. You just can write some java code based on the key-valued parameter and collect results:

```
public interface TableNameRepository extends CrudRepository<TableName, Long> {
  List<TableName> findByStatusAndNumIn(String status, Collection<Integer> nums);
}

List<TableName> result = new ArrayList<>();

List<TableName> itemGood = findByStatusAndNumIn("Good", numsGood);
List<TableName> itemBad = findByStatusAndNumIn("Bad", numsBad);

result.addAll(itemGood);
result.addAll(itemBad);
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of equal size lists, I suggest creating an object with both status and num and provide a list of those - I called it CustomCriteria below.  Since there is no straightforward way to handle this with standard spring data query methods I believe the best way is to do this with criteria builder in a custom repository that builds the list of OR's from a list of AND predicates based on the criteria entries in the provided list.  For example:

```
    public List<YourTable> findMatching(List<CustomCriteria> customCriteriaList) {
        CriteriaBuilder criteriaBuilder = entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();
        CriteriaQuery<YourTable> criteriaQuery = criteriaBuilder.createQuery(YourTable.class);
        Root<YourTable> itemRoot = criteriaQuery.from(YourTable.class);

        List<Predicate> predicates = new ArrayList<>(customCriteriaList.size());
        for (CustomCriteria customCriteria : customCriteriaList) {

            Predicate predicateForNum
                    = criteriaBuilder.equal(itemRoot.get("num"), customCriteria.getNum());
            Predicate predicateForStatus
                    = criteriaBuilder.equal(itemRoot.get("status"), customCriteria.getStatus());
            predicates.add(criteriaBuilder.and(predicateForNum, predicateForStatus));
        }

        Predicate finalPredicate = criteriaBuilder.or(predicates.toArray(new Predicate[predicates.size()]));
        criteriaQuery.where(finalPredicate);
        return entityManager.createQuery(criteriaQuery).getResultList();
    }
```